# Does "inanimate object" mean an object that is "not alive" or an object that is "not moving" or both?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, polysemes

I recently became confused by the term "inanimate object", because "inanimate" can have two meanings (from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inanimate))

> 1 : not animate:
>
> a : **not endowed with life** or spirit
>
> b : **lacking** consciousness or **power of motion**

I am thus unsure if "inanimate object" refers to not alive, not moving, or both.

In other words, it seems obvious that a **table (not moving, not alive)** is an inanimate object.  However, what about these edge cases:

1) Is a **drone (moving, not alive)** an inanimate object?

2) Is a **tree (not moving, alive)** an inanimate object?

Comment: There are degrees of animation. *Inanimate* sounds most like statues and the like - lifeless and immobile, but lifelike.

Comment: You've already provided a dictionary definition that clearly shows both senses of the word. So, it's not clear why you're asking which it means; obviously, it can mean either. (As you demonstrate.) It seems you've already answered your own question—at least in general terms. Context will determine its particular meaning in a particular sentence.

Answer (score 2):

From a brief look at the OED, it seems that over the centuries both ***inanimate*** and its antonym *animate* have been used variously -  to describe things that are living/not living, things that have life or are lifeless, or things that move/do not move.

**Its specific meaning, therefore it would seem, can vary according to context - so a drone, a tree, a dead being can all be described as *inanimate*.**

> ***Animate***
>
> 1. Endowed with life, living, alive; (esp. in later use) alive and having the power of movement, like an animal. In quot. a1398   ‘animat
>      virtu’ = animal spirit n. 1a. ▸ a1398   J. Trevisa tr. Bartholomaeus
>      Anglicus De Proprietatibus Rerum (BL Add. 27944) (1975) I. vi. xxvi.
>      335   Wakinge is nouȝt elles but fre [MS from] schedinge of spiritis
>      into þe lymes of felynge and of meuynge, and doinge þe worchinge of þe
>      animat vertu [L. animalis virtutis] in þe body.
>
> ?a1425   tr. Guy de Chauliac Grande Chirurgie (N.Y. Acad. Med.) f. 51
>   (MED)   [Woundes] made of bodiez inanimate, as swerd..Or of animate,
>   as of puncture of venenous bestez.
>
> c1475   Court of Sapience (Trin. Cambr.) (1927) l. 1126 (MED)   Good
>   watyr, that noble element..Hys dropes swete eke byn most nutrytyf And
>   cause of lyfe to eche thyng animate.
>
> 1598   A. M. tr. J. Guillemeau Frenche Chirurg. 51/4   Mans bodye is
>   the most delicatest amongst all the animate bodyes.
>
> 1605   T. Tymme tr. J. Du Chesne Pract. Chymicall & Hermeticall
>   Physicke ii. i. 102   Phylosophers..have affirmed the magnet or
>   loadstone to be animate.
>
> 1667   Philos. Trans. (Royal Soc.) 2 580   Corruption of Bodies
>   Inanimat and Animat.
>
> 1728   E. Chambers Cycl. (at cited word)   In Mechanicks, Animate
>   Power is used to denote a Man or Brute.
>
> 1775   J. Adair Hist. Amer. Indians 45   They apply the word heart,
>   only to animate beings.
>
> 1841   T. Carlyle On Heroes i. 5   That men should have
>   worshipped..stocks and stones, and all manner of animate and inanimate
>   objects.
>
> 1872   Trans. Amer. Philol. Assoc. 3 83   The American Indian
>   distinction of animate and inanimate objects.
>
> 1922   T. A. Coward Bird Haunts & Nature Memories 141   Jizz may be
>   applied to or possessed by any animate and some inanimate objects, yet
>   we cannot clearly define it.
>
> 1944   Americas 1 211   It distinguishes between animate and
>   non-animate being.
>
> 2002   N. Drury Dict. Esoteric 13/1   Inanimate objects as well as
>   animate ones have a lifeforce or energy quite distinct from the
>   physical form.
>
> ***Inanimate***
>
> > 1. Not animated or alive; destitute of life, lifeless; spec. not endowed with animal life, as in inanimate nature, that part of nature
> >        which is without sensation, i.e. all outside the animal world.
> >
> > a1555   J. Bradford Let. in J. Foxe Actes & Monuments (1570) III.
> >     1835/1   Shall we see sacrifice and Gods seruice done to an inanimate
> >     creature and be mumme?
> >
> > 1643   J. Steer tr. Fabricius Exper. Chyrurg. xvi. 65   Inanimate
> >     creatures, as Trees, and the like.
> >
> > 1785   W. Cowper Task i. 197   Nature inanimate employs sweet sounds,
> >     But animated Nature sweeter still.
> >
> > 1828   Scott Fair Maid of Perth ii, in Chron. Canongate 2nd Ser. I. 31
> >     The beauties of inanimate nature.
> >
> > 1866   H. P. Liddon Bampton Lect. iv. 152   At His bidding life
> >     returns to inanimate corpses.
> >
> > 1880   J. Muirhead Inst. of Gaius & Rules of Ulpian Digest 632   He
> >     who..did damage to any inanimate property..was liable in its highest
> >     value.